# Where can I find the server.log file when using Glassfish?

Tags: jakarta-ee, logging, deployment, glassfish, java-ee-6

I get the following error:

```
deploy?DEFAULT=C:\Users\Bart\Documents\SE Fontys\S61\2013groep081\PTS-ESD\rekeningadministratie\build\web&name=RekeningAdministratie&contextroot=/rekeningadministratie&force=true failed on GlassFish Server 3.1.2 
 Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app : WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for type [AutoDAOJPA] with qualifiers [@Default] at injection point [[field] @Inject factuur.Prijsbepaling.autoDAO]. Please see server.log for more details.
```

Which says I can see the server.log for more details. I have tried the glassfish/[mydomain]/logs but it's not there

Note: The error itself is solved and it had to do with using an Injected class before it was injected. Still the question remains for the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The glassfish log is located in

```
glassfish\domains\<yourdomain>\logs
```

under the glassfish installation folder.

(You wrote - glassfish[mydomain]\logs, which is not quite the same.)